# Houdini arm to x86 translation "Unsupported feature" error when using shared STL in Android NDK app

Tags: stl, android-ndk

I created an Android Studio project from [this sample NDK project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk/Teapot) provided by Google and changed a couple things so I could try to leverage [Houdini](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/11/21/libhoudini-what-it-means-for-developers.html) arm to x86 translation:

1. In `app/build.gradle` I set `abiFilters` to `armeabi-v7a`.
2. In `Application.mk` I changed `APP_ABI` from `all` to `armeabi-v7a` so that x86 native libraries won't be created.
3. Also in `Application.mk`, I changed `APP_STL` from `stlport_static` to `gnustl_shared`.

You can see the modified code in [this repo](https://github.com/lyahdav/AndroidTeapot).

Then I ran the app in the [BlueStacks emulator](https://www.bluestacks.com/), which supports Houdini. I get the following error:

```
11-21 00:42:19.742 9947-9947/? D/houdini: [9947] Loading library(version: 4.0.8.45720 RELEASE)... successfully.
11-21 00:42:19.742 9947-9947/? D/houdini: [9947] Unsupported feature (ID:0x10600cae).
11-21 00:42:19.742 9947-9947/? D/houdini: [9947] Open Native Library /data/app-lib/com.sample.teapot-2/libTeapotNativeActivity.so failed.
...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.teapot/com.sample.teapot.TeapotNativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.sample.teapot-2/libTeapotNativeActivity.so
```

If I make `APP_STL` any of the [supported values](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#c_runtime_libraries) with `shared` I get this error, and with `static` it works fine. I'd like to get `shared` working, to solve [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12246) in React Native. Does shared STL not work with Houdini? Any workarounds?

Comment: Moving _to_ houdini is a step in the wrong direction. Targeting x86 will be better for you and your users.

Comment: We don't want to target x86 for the reasons described here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12246#issuecomment-324706053

Comment: Split APK is also better for your users.

Comment: The link I posted in the previous comment mentions why split APK isn't a good option for some teams